# Get recently viewed products array in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've got the problem that i have to highly customize a magento ecommerce shop.
Therefore it would be great if i could have the data requested in

> \app\design\frontend\avalanche\default\template\reports\product_viewed_details.phtml

via

```
$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()
```

I already tried to get it via

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('report/product_view')->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

, but the only thing i get is an empty array.

Could someone please help me? I'm driving a little bit crazy over here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried :

`$collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use aliases, to produce more 'friendly' code:

`$collection = Mage::getBlockSingleton('reports/product_viewed')->getItemsCollection();`

Comment: How to get same collection in Magento 2?