# How to get a list of last viewed products in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to access the list of last viewed items using the below code:

```
 $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
 $model = Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed');
 //
 $_collection = $model->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
                  ->excludeProductIds($model->getExcludeProductIds())
                  ->addUrlRewrite()
                  ->setPageSize($columnCount)
                  ->setCurPage(1);
 //
 $_collection->addPriceData();
 $_collection->addIndexFilter();
 $_collection->setAddedAtOrder();
 //
 Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($_collection);
```

I copied this from the Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract but this is giving the products in the creation order.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Prasanth will ever come back to this but I too having been trying to get a simple list of products without [using a block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11413918/471559) which may not always be available.  Eventually I found you need this:

```
$viewedCollection = Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addIndexFilter();
```

The secret is in `addIndexFilter()`, it uses the current customer or - if not logged in - the current visitor instead. From this you can loop through as with any other collection or extract a single array:

```
$viewedProductIds = $viewedCollection->getColumnValues('product_id');
```

Comment: I realised I didn't make this very clear.  The key is to leave off `setAddedAtOrder()` from the original, and anything else you don't need.